# Understanding a code sample

Tags: asp.net

I found an example in witch I do not understand something in asp.net webforms.The example is made using a details view control.Here is the code:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID=”DropDownList1” runat=”server” 
     DataSourceID=”GenresDataSource“ DataTextField=”Name” DataValueField=”Id” 
     SelectedValue=’<%# Bind(“GenreId”) %>’>
</asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

In the dropdown list I understand that:

- DataTextField - represent the name of the item that is shown in the dropdown
- DataValueField = represents the value of the selected Item
- SelectedValue - I think it represent the item the user selects but I am not sure corect                                    me if I am wrong

If what I said in the the top is true what does this statement generate in the case witch GenreId is a column in a database:

```
<%# Bind(“GenreId”) %>’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will set the selected value of the dropdown to the "GenreId". So the default value of the dropdown will be the ID.